# Bash script combine echo say and read

Tags: macos, bash

Using a bash script on Mac OS X, how do I combine `echo`, `say` and `read` to make it cleaner and less line of code?  The below script works but to me there are too many lines.  Thanks a lot for your help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

clear

echo -n "Enter your first name: "
say "Enter your first name"
read -r name
echo -n "Enter your last name: "
say "Enter your last name"
read -r lastname
say "Good morning ${name}${lastname}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define functions in `bash`:

```
echoAndSay() {
    say $*
    printf "%s: " "$*"
}

echoAndSay "Enter your first name"
read -r name
echoAndSay "Enter your last name"
read -r lastname
say "Good morning ${name} ${lastname}"
```

Comment: Thanks nohillside it is much better like that.  When I run the first time I received an error message, I think it suppose to be like that: printf "%s:" "$*" which I did and it work. Thanks again.